# How to pass data from ifram to parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

i am creating a vue js application that is hosted in my subdomain

and i want load a form from my main site using iframe.simple i want to load a form from my primary domain to my subdomain through i frame.And is working perfectly

```
<iframe ref="formFrame" @load="afterLoad()" :src="url"></iframe>
```

And now i have a function in my vue js app like

```
displaySuccess(data){
            console.log("data from server: "+data);
        }
```

And this function should be triggered from my form. so i addedd a code like below in the form

```
window.parent.displaySuccess(text);
```

But it is not triggering.How can i call parent methods from iframe form.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `window.postMessage()` method safely (enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it like in your example).

This is a basic example for a duplex communication between a parent and an Iframe.

Parent -> IFrame

```js
   iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('hello world', '*'); // from parent
```

```js
window.onmessage = function(e) { // inside the iframe
    if (e.data == 'hello world') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
};
```

IFrame -> Parent

```js
window.onmessage = function(e) { // inside the parent
    if (e.data == 'hello world') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
};
```

```js
window.top.postMessage('hello world', '*') //inside the iframe
```

**Window.postMessage** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: When i did this, i can do postMessage from parent to iframe, but couldnt pass from ifram form to parent,it doesn't triggering

Comment: I edited the answer with a basic example for you to use

Comment: i want to pass the data bothside, so postMessage will work on both side??

Comment: yes. please also check out this article for more details:
https://bl.ocks.org/pbojinov/8965299

Comment: Thank you, it is working fine as expected